# VBA Runtime Error when connection to SQL Database

Tags: sql, excel, vba, connection

I'm trying to connect to a `SQL Server` from multiple PCs in the same domain.

When using the following code:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 'Neue Verbindung initialisieren

'Verbindung einrichten'
conn.ConnectionString = "PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=WWDDB;Database=01Projekt;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
conn.Open
```

`conn.Open` returns the error:

> Error on login for the user 'XXXX'

Comment: Why are you using a named user with `Integrated Security`?  Use one or the other

Comment: Honestly i dont know... removing integrated Security made it work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are using a named user with `Integrated Security`.  These two modes are incompatible.

Try removing `Integrated Security=SSPI`:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=WWDDB;Database=01Projekt;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;Trusted_Connection=True;" conn.Open
```

Or the named user:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=WWDDB;Database=01Projekt;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;" conn.Open
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my snippet, try it :

```
Set cnConn = New ADODB.Connection

With cnConn
.Provider = "SQLOLEDB.1"
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.ConnectionTimeout = 0
.Properties("Data Source").Value = ' serverName
.Properties("Password").Value = ' pswd
.Properties("User ID").Value = ' userName
.Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = ' init DB
.Open
End With
```